# System user in Ubuntu server does not search right TexLive path

Tags: path, latex, ubuntu-14.04

**Short question**: my system user (name `sharelatex`) does not search in manually installed TexLive in `/usr/local/texlive` but search in `/usr/share/texlive` (I don't know why there is this folder here, I didn't install TexLive from Ubuntu repo). My another normal user and root user can search well in `/usr/local/texlive`. How can I force `sharelatex` user to search in `/usr/local/texlive`? Thanks!

**Detail**: I'm trying to install sharelatex onto my Ubuntu server.
I have manually installed TexLive using:

> wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
>
> tar -xvf install-tl-unx.tar.gz
>
> cd install-tl-*
>
> sudo ./install-tl

While installing, I have created a system user named `sharelatex` and added it to group `sharelatex` by these 2 commands:

> sudo adduser --system --home /var/www/sharelatex --no-create-home --group sharelatex
>
> sudo chown -R sharelatex:sharelatex /var/www/sharelatex

When I login as root or normal user, the output of the command

> which latex

is

> /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/latex

However,when I try to run the same command as `sharelatex` user:

> sudo -u sharelatex which latex

the output is

> /usr/bin/latex

Comment: Vote to close as off-topic. Re-ask on SuperUser and mention `$PATH`

Comment: I've searched about this $PATH problem and even tried to add TexLive directory to `/etc/environment` but it didn't work. However, I have figured out how to fix it as answer below! I know the $PATH question has been asked in SuperUser but all of answers I found there didn't work with me. I'm so sorry for being off-topic. Is there anyway to move this question to SuperUser as I think this might still benefit some other users.

Comment: Did you put `/usr/local/bin` in the `PATH` definition in `/etc/environment`?

Answer (score 0):

I also think this was the problem about $PATH with system user `sharelatex`. Even I have tried to put my TexLive directory to `/etc/environment`, my `sharelatex` user still cannot find it. However, after take a closer look at `sharelatex` service files, I see that the path for `sharelatex` seems to be set again when `sharelatex` execute latex command. Here is how to fix it:

**Step 1**. Search for your upstart files `sharelatex-SERVICE.conf` where `SERVICE` should be replaced with `web`, `chat`,`clsi`,... Full list as below:

- `sharelatex-chat.conf`
- `sharelatex-clsi.conf`
- `sharelatex-docstore.conf`
- `sharelatex-document-updater.conf`
- `sharelatex-filestore.conf`
- `sharelatex-real-time.conf`
- `sharelatex-spelling.conf`
- `sharelatex-tags.conf`
- `sharelatex-template.conf`
- `sharelatex-track-changes.conf`
- `sharelatex-web.conf`

If you follow the installation manual from sharelatex github, these files are probably in `/etc/init`.

**Step 2**. In each file, you will see this line:

> LATEX_PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux

This line will set LATEX_PATH variable to the right TexLive. And in the ending of the file, you will see the line that will execute TexLive command:

> exec sudo -u $USER -g $GROUP env SHARELATEX_CONFIG=$SHARELATEX_CONFIG NODE_ENV=production PATH=$PATH:$LATEX_PATH $NODE app.js >> /var/log/sharelatex/$SERVICE.log 2>&1

What you need to do it to swap `$PATH:$LATEX_PATH` to become `PATH=$LATEX_PATH:$PATH`. By doing this, the directory to the right TexLive will be search first.

Make this change to all the `sharelatex-SERVICE.conf` listed above.

After editing all those files, you might want to restart all those services (search for restart upstart services), or maybe just restart the machine.

Comment: You didn't ask how to change the `sharelatex` service; you asked how to get a user to find latex in `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`.